# Customize state_dict() and load_state_dict() pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, save, customization

I have a nested set of classes (each of type `torch.nn.module`). I need to do some preprocessing before saving the weights of one of the nested classes. Is it possible to override the `state_dict()` function so that I can insert the preprocessing in my custom implementation?

Sample code:

```
Class A(torch.nn.module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.b1 = B1()
        self.b2 = B2()

Class B1(torch.nn.module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.var = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor((3, 5), dtype=float))

Class B2(torch.nn.module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.var = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor((3, 5), dtype=float))

    def state_dict():
        # I want to override the default state_dict like this, but this does not work. 
        # Is there a way to achieve this?
        bool_var = self.var.bool().cpu().numpy()
        state_dict1 = super.state_dict()
        state_dict1.update({'var': bool_var})
        return state_dict1

    def load_state_dict(state_dict):
        state_dict['var'] = state_dict['var'].float()
        super.load_state_dict(state_dict)
        return
```

Specifically, for one of the classes, I want to convert the variable to `bool` before saving it and convert it back to `float` while loading it. I can't make the tensor as `bool` by default since it needs to be learned as a float value.

The code I am working with is [this](https://github.com/apchenstu/TensoRF/blob/main/models/tensorBase.py#L248--L263). Here, they've hard-coded saving of such variable. I don't want to do that. I want `state_dict()` and `load_state_dict()` to automatically take care of the conversion.

PS: While [this discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-customize-the-module-state-dict-load-state-dict/139604/4) indicates that customizing is not possible, I am hoping PyTorch would have added it in the recent versions or there are some other ways of achieving this.

Comment: What is the question here? Is the code you provided not working?

Comment: Yes. I cannot override the `state_dict()` and `load_state_dict()` method in my custom class.

Answer (score 0):

You can override both methods, but your code is not correct. You have typos in your code: `class` instead of `Class`, and `torch.nn.Module` instead of `torch.nn.module`. The parent class has to be *called* with `super()`: [`super().state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.state_dict) and [`super().load_state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict). When creating a wrapper, you should forward all incoming positional and keyword arguments to the parent method (with `*args, **kwargs`). Lastly, you omitted the `self` argument.

With all of this in mind, here is a possible implementation:

```
class B2(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.var = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.rand((3, 5), dtype=float))

    def state_dict(self, *args, **kwargs):
        state_dict1 = super().state_dict(*args, **kwargs)
        bool_var = self.var.bool().cpu().numpy()
        state_dict1.update({'var': bool_var})
        return state_dict1

    def load_state_dict(self, state_dict, *args, **kwargs):
        state_dict['var'] = torch.from_numpy(state_dict['var']).float()
        super().load_state_dict(state_dict, *args, **kwargs)
        return
```

So you can do:

```
>>> state = B2().state_dict()
OrderedDict([('var',
              array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
                     [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
                     [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]]))])

>>> B2().load_state_dict(state)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I used hooks as suggested [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-customize-the-module-state-dict-load-state-dict/139604/4). But hooks can change anytime. I'll try your answer out.